# Missing something in the calculation of entropy

Tags: r, probability, distributions, entropy, information-theory

**Problem summary: How does the calculation of entropy differentiate between the "randomness" of two sequences that comprise the same set of elements?**

Following [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7515030/) paper, let's say I have two vectors, `v1` which is produced from an obviously predictable pattern, and `v2`, which is less so. The two vectors have the same mean and variance.

```
v1 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
v2 <- c(0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0)
```

Section 1 of the linked paper describes the failure of classical statistics to differentiate between these two vectors with respect to "randomness", and contrasts this failure with the measure of entropy, defined in equation 1:

$$H(x) = -\sum_{x \in X}{p(x)*log(p(x))}$$

I'm not seeing how this equation takes into account sequence order, as the background information in the paper seems to suggest. And indeed when I calculate entropy (using the empirical PMF) for each of these two vectors, I get equal values.

```
entropy <- function(v){

  # empirical probability mass function:
  pmf <- function(vec){
    sapply(vec, function(x){
      length(vec[vec==x]) / length(vec)  
    })
  }

  pi <- pmf(v)
  sum(pi*log(1/pi))
}
```

```
entropy(v1)
```

6.931472

```
entropy(v2)
```

6.931472

What am I missing? I have to believe it's my interpretation of their use of probability distribution. I'd thought perhaps the calculation of the PMF should consider only up to element $i$:

```
entropy2 <- function(v){

  pmf <- function(vec){
    sapply(1:length(vec), function(i){
      sample_set <- vec[1:i]
      length(sample_set[sample_set==v[i]]) / length(sample_set)  
    })
  }

  pi <- pmf(v)
  sum(pi*log(1/pi))
}
```

But in this case, calculated entropy for `v1` is slightly *higher* than for `v2`.

```
entropy2(v1)
```

6.362594

```
entropy2(v2)
```

6.321197

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The equation $H(x)$ *does not* consider the sequence order.** To consider the sequence the probability distribution $p$ would need to be a distribution over the vectors, telling you what is the probability of observing different vectors. To calculate it, you would need to observe *many vectors* and calculate the empirical probabilities of different vectors (in your case, millions of vectors since there are $2^{20}$ possible sequences). It is not possible to calculate probabilities of observing different sequences from a single (or two) sequences.

Because of the reasons above, using empirical probabilities would not work here. The practical solution could be to have some kind of model that would approximate the distribution $p$ and given a sequence, predict the probabilities. Such models are able to interpolate to some extent, so to calculate the probabilities they usually need less data.

Comment: Well, what the linked paper proposes is another solution, to use some approximation (discussed therein) of entropy rate, but it would need much longer series than in the post